# How to get Sublime Text 3 to lint love2d Lua?

Tags: windows, lua, scripting, sublimetext3, love2d

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows for my Lua projects. I have a linter plugin installed that uses Luacheck. I'm also using love2d and Luacheck doesn't recognize all the love2d-specific syntax.

How can I get Sublime to lint normal and love2d Lua at the same time?

Comment: Uhh, doesn't love2d use standard Lua syntax? Can you give an example of something the linter doesn't understand?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to know what you tried. Without that it looks like you didn't and want us to write a tutorial or find information for you.